# Block event invitations from a specific person on Facebook

Tags: facebook-events

Is there a way to stop a specific person from sending you event invitations without removing them as a friend on Facebook? If it isn't built in, perhaps there is an application that lets you remove yourself from events after you are invited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is when you click decline on one of the person's event invitations, there is now a popup box which asks you to leave a message, and there's a link there to block event invites from that person.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this answer is not valid anymore in 2014. I've created a [new question here.](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/67387/33242)

Comment: As from 2017: >Settings >Blocking >Block event invites. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PA_NKK_UW4s - Still hope that Facebook introduces a global option.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to stop receiving Event Invites by following these steps:

1. Go to [Manage Blocking](http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=blocking)
2. Add persona non grata to **Block invites from**.

> Once you block event invites from someone, you'll automatically ignore future event requests from that friend.

Comment: Hmm, why is this accepted? This doesn't block invitations from those people; it just hides event info on your profile from them. ( [According to Rupert in this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7095/how-can-i-prevent-lessen-event-spam-on-facebook) )

Comment: @Casebash The current accepted answer is not correct as Jonik has pointed out. I left some tips and pointers on [How can I prevent/lessen event spam on Facebook?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7095/how-can-i-prevent-lessen-event-spam-on-facebook)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now it is possible to block invites from specific people.

Comment: This approach still works, but lists have been moved.  The lists mentioned in this answer are now [here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=blocking).

Comment: Thanks @DuckTapeal, I've updated answer to point to the new location.

Answer (score 2):

For a page that allows you to see everyone who's currently blocked in one way or another (event invites, app invites, totally blocked, etc.) and allows you to add more people to block, currently this URL works like a charm: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=blocking

[image: Block event invites]

Comment: How does your answer differ from [Domas’s one](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/2709/1512)?

Comment: Doma's answer is perfectly sufficient in response to the question; I think mine goes a bit further in describing the nature of the page you're going to.  I think the edit by Al Everett adds something as well, a nice visual context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Chrome extension called "[Facebook Invitations Blocker](http://www.mbanna.info/facebook-invitations-blocker-chrome-extension/)" to block all invitations (Like pages, Join events and try Apps).