# Block event invites from non-friends in Facebook (2014)

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-events

How do I block/ignore event invites from non-friends, sent to me through a group?

I don't want to leave the group, and turning off all notifications of the group didn't help ignoring the event invites, they still get through.

I'm basically looking for an answer [similar to this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35254/33242), but for Facebook of the year 2014.

[This other answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/2709/33242) is not valid anymore either as it allows me to block friends only.

Answer (score 2):

Just figured this out! First option... you can always just simply block the person, but then you will not be able to access the pages for any event they organize at all, even if you have the link for it. I didn't like this option.

Second option... Go to your Events page and look at it in list view, not calendar view. Find one event of the person you want to stop getting invites from. Hover over the top right corner of the box for that event, and the option for "Remove me from Event" will pop up. Select that, then a new option should appear at the bottom of the event box, saying "Stop invites from..." Voila!

Comment: Blocking the person only works if you're friends with them. People who are group admins and are non-friends can invite you to events but you can't block them. The second option yielded [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PZay0.png). I unfortunately don't have the option to stop invites from the inviter. Did have this option a year or two ago.